# Combing SQL Query Result set to sum rows with matching text values

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    V_NAME AS VendorName, 
    P_QOH AS Quantity,
    CASE 
        WHEN  P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%blade%'  THEN 'Blade'
        WHEN  P_DESCRIPT LIKE  '%screw%'  THEN 'Screw Driver'
        WHEN  P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%hammer%'  THEN 'Hammer'
        ELSE 'OTHERS' 
    END AS ProductCategory
FROM Product, Vendor
WHERE 
    ( 
        P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%blade%'
        OR P_DESCRIPT LIKE  '%screw%'
        OR P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%hammer%' 
    )
    AND Product.V_CODE = Vendor.V_CODE;
```

This Query gives me the result:

```
Gomez Bros.|32|Blade
Gomez Bros.|18|Blade
ORDVA, Inc.|8|Blade
ORDVA, Inc.|6|Blade
Bryson, Inc.|23|Hammer
Bryson, Inc.|172|Screw Driver
D&E Supply|237|Screw Driver
Gomez Bros.|237|Screw Driver
Gomez Bros.|23|Hammer
Bryson, Inc.|32|Blade
Bryson, Inc.|237|Screw Driver
```

I've tried numerous things to no avail. What I want to do is combine rows within the result set that have the same tool name (e.g. "Hammer, Screw Driver, Blade"), combining the values of the individual rows for each company listed.

So, for example, I want the first two rows to read as

```
Gomez Bros.|50|Blade
```

Combining the two rows with the values 32 and 18 that both have a type "Blade"

Any help is appreciated! I'm very new to SQL. Struggling here. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    v.V_NAME AS VendorName, 
    SUM(p.tP_QOH) AS Quantity,
    CASE 
        WHEN  p.P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%blade%'  THEN 'Blade'
        WHEN  p.P_DESCRIPT LIKE  '%screw%'  THEN 'Screw Driver'
        WHEN  p.P_DESCRIPT  LIKE  '%hammer%'  THEN 'Hammer'
        ELSE 'OTHERS' 
    END AS ProductCategory
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Vendor v ON p.V_CODE = v.V_CODE
WHERE 
       p.P_DESCRIPT LIKE '%blade%'
    OR p.P_DESCRIPT LIKE '%screw%'
    OR p.P_DESCRIPT LIKE '%hammer%'
GROUP BY v.V_CODE, VendorName, ProductCategory
```

Notes:

- *always* use proper, moder join syntax (with the `ON` keyword) instead of old-school joins (with a comma in the `from` clause)
- it is best to prefix each column with the table it belongs to (I made a few assumptions that you might need to review)
- table aliases make the query shorter to write and read

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for the help. It gets me ALMOST there... now I'm trying to figure out how to remove duplicates from the vendor inserts, which is making the product counts (P_QOH) way higher than it should be...
```
INSERT INTO P VALUES('X6SW-23116','2.5-in. wd. screw, 15'                ,'24-FEB-2016',237,100,  8.45,0.00,21225);
INSERT INTO P VALUES('W6SW-23116','2.5-in. wd. screw, 15'                ,'24-APR-2016',237,100,  8.45,0.00,21225);
```
For instance, the above 4 rows from the Product table should only be counted once as they're all the same item

Comment: Essentially, the query is taking all rows from the Product table from the same Vendor that have the same P_DESCRIPT (ex: '2.5-in. wd. screw, 15') and combining them together. I need it to only take unique P_DESCRIPT or Omit duplicate V_CODE (vendor codes) for matching P_DESCRIPTS ..  thanks again for your help!